# Detecting the end of an https message

Tags: sockets, rest, http, ssl, nonblocking

i am trying to implement a non blocking SSL connection using nio sockets & SSlEngine. Unfornetly the message must contains enough data so it can be decrypted by the sslengine. And i am wondering how does a normal SSLSocket in blocking mode know that the https message have fully arrived??

Is there any flag announcing the end a https message/packet?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the http headers to see if Content-Length (the length of the packet) is included?

Comment: it is not http but https. Thus, i can not check the header until i have decrypted it. But to decrypt it i need to have the full message,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSL packs the data into records and each record contains the size at the beginning. So the SSLengine itself knows how many data it needs. According to http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2004/11/03/ssl-nio.html a call to `unwrap` would return `BUFFER_UNDERFLOW` if the record is not fully read and thus can not be decrypted and you need to read more data from the connection in this case.